# What matplotlib rc parameter controls legend title size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an rc parameter to control the size of a legend title in matplotlib? It's possible to set with

```
ax.legend().set_title(prop={"size": title_size})
```

But it does not seem to correspond to the rc parameters `legend.fontsize` or `axes.titlesize`.

What parameter controls the size of this element?

Answer (score 4):

`rcParams["legend.title_fontsize"]` will be available in [matplotlib v3.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.3/users/whats_new.html#legend-now-has-a-title-fontsize-kwarg-and-rcparam).

Answer (score 3):

Inspecting the source code and trying around a little bit it seems to me that there is no such rc parameter. The default font size is used.

It is a bit surprising to me - probably it's because legend titles are not used very often.

Update 2017/18/09: Still not possible. If anybody of you would need it, please open an issue for this on github. [Github Link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Not sure... This answer is more than three years old.

Comment: checked again: unchanged. Still no rcParameter for this.

Comment: Nearly 4 years later: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10121

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
plt.rc('font', size=20)
```

in Matplotlib 3.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = {
      'legend.title_fontsize' : 'x-large'
       }
pylab.rcParams.update(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

plt.rc('legend',fontsize=25, title_fontsize= 25)